# Ubuntu Linux + Windows 7 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, format

when I was installing Linux I planned for a dual boot of Windows7 / Ubuntu.

When I was installing Linux, I was choosing the partition for which to install Linux. I accidentally formatted the partition of my windows 7 storage (640.1 GB). I didn't format the windows boot Loaders, and now when I start up my laptop, I cannot see a dual boot, it goes straight to Linux. I realize the storage on my windows 7 is gone, but how do I get windows  7 back. This was built in with the laptop, and I may not have the disk.

Comment: @begueradj No, I had windows and linux (linux on usb) as a dual boot until I fully installed Linux. I didn't erase the all disk as the first option said, but I formatted windows 7 storage, but not boot loaders. How do I go on windows now? Have I screwed it up fully?

Comment: which new Linux did you install ?

Comment: @begueradj Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: *accidentally formatted the partition of my windows 7 storage* this means you can not get back your Windows 7 at all.

Comment: @begueradj Guess I'll have to get the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a recent post on SuperSite for Windows that discussed how to get a clean ISO for Windows 7.

http://winsupersite.com/windows-7/legally-download-clean-windows-7-iso-directly-microsoft

Hopefully that will get you what you need. As an aside, you could boot in to linux from a USB drive and there are some recovery tools that you could use to recover files if there's anything that you would really like to get back. It is not a perfect science, so don't get your hopes up too much but it's worth checking out.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: As a side note, the Microsoft Windows 7 recovery site will only work for none OEM versions of Windows 7 and because of this it can't be used if Windows was pre-installed on a system. The site will do a check against the product key to see which version it is.